# How can I simulate the process of transmitting BPSK signal from start to end?

Tags: digital-communications, bandpass

I would like to simulate the process of transmitting a binary phase shift keying (BPSK) signal from start to finish, going through each step over additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN) channel. I know how to start, but I'm not sure how to do some parts in the channel and receiver

To start suppose I have these parameters for the simulation

- Baseband bandwidth $W=1$ MHz
- The bit time is $T_b=1/W=1 \mu$s
- The sampling frequency $f_s=4$ MHz
- The sampling period $T_s=0.25 \mu$s
- The number of samples/bit = $T_b/T_s=4$ samples/bit

The steps in MATLAB

1. Define the parameters

```
W = 10^6; % Baseband bandwidth
Tb = 1/W; % Bit duration
fs = 4*10^6; % Sampling rate
Ts = 1/fs; % sampling period
J = Tb/Ts;% samples/bit

N = 10^5; %number of bits to be generated
t = 0:Ts:(N-1)*Ts; % time vector of N bit

fc = 15/Tb; % carrier frequency
```

2. Generate the bits, and convert them to samples that follow a rectangular pulse shaping, and multiply the samples by a carrier with a carrier frequency $f_c=15/T_b=15$ MHz

```
x = 2*(rand(N,1) > 0.5)-1; % generate a sequence of +1 -1
xs = repelem(x,J); % This repeats each bit J times, since the pulse shaping is rectangular
s = xs.*cos(2*pi*fc.*t);
```

Here were things start to be unclear to me. Do we divide the energy bit to the samples? For example, if we have an energy bit to noise ration of 8 dB, does this mean that the sample energy to noise ration would be $\gamma = 8-10\log_{10}(J)$ dB? Which means that we add the noise as following

```
Eb_N0 = 8;
gamma = Eb_N0 - 10*log10(J);
n = (1/sqrt(gamma)).*randn(N*J,1);
r = xs + n;
```

3. Assume we added the noise and we obtained the received signal $r(t)$

```
r = s + n;
```

How could I extract the bits again and make detection? I know mathematically we need a correlator with the basis function, which is an integration over the bit duration. But how can we implement this in MATLAB?

Comment: Are you assuming a simple AWGN channel with no multipath, and complete synchronization from transmitter to receiver both in frequency and time? Otherwise  If from start to finish you would also be concerned with channel equalization (due to multipath in the channel), automatic gain control, timing recovery and carrier recovery.

Comment: You need this book: "Software Receiver Design", by Johnson, Sethares, and Klein. The first edition, called "Telecommunications breakdown", is free online.

Comment: @DanBoschen Yes, just a simple AWGN channel. I'd like to follow the exact process in MATLAB.

Comment: @Math_Novice that would include synchronization to be anything meaningful. That is a lot more than can be squeezed into an answer here, and coding implementation is outside the scope for this site. This is a major part of a course I teach “DSP for Software Radio” that is starting next month, you can check that out here: https://ieeeboston.org/2023-courses/

Comment: @DanBoschen Thank you. I just wanted to know how to recover the symbols from the samples at the receiver.

Comment: @Math_Novice that is what I am referring to. Also link was updated it is now https://ieeeboston.org/courses/